# How to make code (python, java, scala) looks as beautiful as algorithms?

Tags: sourcecode

I know there is a very good package for listing code [(listing package)](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) but codes are ugly.

I know there are some good package for algorithms (algorithmics, algorithm2e, etc). But I want to write runnable code not only printable one.

So, is there any way to include programming code into a tex article that looks as nice as algorithms? Or, is there any (automatic) way to convert a programming code into a latex algorithm?

Some ideas that I have explored but so far they were not good enough.

- Converting Python to latex.

  I found a Python library to convert Python expressions into latex based on this question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867028/converting-a-python-numeric-expression-to-latex
- Writing in literate programming style (noweb)

  Problem: CWEB output is nice but noweb output is just code listing. CWEB unfortunately was designed for C language.

Edit:
Well, see the example below (I got from http://www.literateprogramming.com/cweb.pdf)

[image: CWEB output]

Why is this so nice? For example, the operator "!=" was converted to latex \neq. Or the "!" boolean operator was converted to "\neg". And so on...

Now, another example with algorithmicx package.

[image: Agorithmics output]

Can we achieve that with listing?

---

### Disclaimer

Since I copied this snippet from CWEB Manual, I have to put this copyright note here...

The printed form of this manual is copyright 1994 by Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, Inc. All rights reserved. The electronic form is copyright  1987, 1990, 1993, 2000 by Silvio Levy and Donald E. Knuth.
Permission is granted to make and distribute verbatim copies of the electronic form of this document provided that the electronic copyright notice and this permission notice are preserved on all copies. Permission is granted to copy and distribute modified versions of the electronic form of this document under the conditions for verbatim copying, provided that the entire resulting derived work is distributed under the terms of a permission notice identical to this one.

Comment: You *really* need to give some idea of what you want the output to look like -- draw it in inkscape for example.  Arguably algorithms made up of English words and properly typeset maths are rather different to listings of source code -- in the latter, every character counts (`1` vs `I` vs `l` can't be assumed to be inferrable from context, limiting your fonts and aesthetic formatting)

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Are you aware of the listings and minted packages?

Comment: Hi, @AndrewSwann. I have explicitly commented about listings package in the first line but same applies to minted.

Comment: it would help if you provided a test document with a sample code (say in verbatim or listings or minted)

Comment: listings is highly customisable.  It will do the conversions you mention with appropriate customisations.  What can't you achieve?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am preparing a show case  and I will update the question.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, I added another example of output that I was looking for. Basically, I want to exchange operators from a specific programming language to math operators. And ideally, other math symbols (e.g.: variable with greek letters, empty set, ...)

Comment: That goal is interesting, but after the process you describe, you don't have code any more, you have a sort of prettified pseudocode -- so your title doesn't really match the question.  But more constructively, you can at least start by mapping some strings to appropriate characters using listings and its `literate` tools.  You might also see [Listings, Literate Programming, and Beautiful Typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2615/28808)

Comment: You can do many of these symbol replacements with suitable minted or listings code, but without an example and a suggestion of what that example should look like hard to say (images of other code written in other languages less help)

Comment: For listings see section 6.4 of the manual a literal replacements entitled "Literate programming"

Comment: @AndrewSwann, I need to admit that I was arrogant to say that we cannot achieve that with listings. Thanks. I am still working in a example and I will give you a better feedback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listings, Literate Programming, and Beautiful Typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/listings-literate-programming-and-beautiful-typography)